# Удаление выбранных CheckBox'ов в gridview

Tags: c#

я хочу удалить данные выбранные с CheckBox'ом. Данные находяться в GridView.

Для этого я определил столб для CheckBox в базе данных, но если даже выбираю несколько строк при нажатии в бутон  УДАЛИТЬ удаляет последнюю выбранную строку.Как я могу решить это? Я действительно много исследовал, но не смог найти полезного решения.

Простите за ломанный Русский :)

Comment: ну и что это? WinForms? WebFroms? WPF? Xamarin? HTML? UWP?

Comment: Вы что то сделали, то есть у вас есть код, что не работает, вы спрашиваете как его починить, но сам код не показываете.

Comment: WinForms. U menya form kotoriy ispolnayet CRUD

Comment: покажите ваш код. который вы пытаетесь исправить

Comment: for (int i = gwkdvlist.SelectedRows.Count; i > 0; i--)

{

var cnn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"];

SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(cnn.ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM ogrenciler WHERE ID= @iID", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ogrenciID", int.Parse(gwkdvlist.Rows[gwlist.SelectedCells.RowIndex]["ogrenciID"].ToString()));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

gwlist.Rows.RemoveAt(gwkdvlist.SelectedCells.RowIndex);

Comment: добавьте код в вопрос, в комментариях код не читаем. Вы ваш вопрос можете редактировать.

Answer (score 0):

1. сформируйте новый список itemsToRemove с ID для удаления элементoв
2. сформируйте запрос на удаления всех элементов из базы данных которые находятся в 
   списке  itemsToRemove

   SqlConnection(cnn.ConnectionString); SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM ogrenciler WHERE ID IN('тут ID1','тут ID2', 'тут ID3' ) , con);

удаляется один элемент потому что WHERE ID= @iID а должно быть WHERE ID IN('','')
либо выполняйте этот запрос (WHERE ID= @iID) в цикле несколько раз для каждого элемента который надо удалить